# Vaadin 23 tabs horizontal mode switch to multi-line

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Is it possible somehow to configure Vaadin 23 horizontal Tab component to work in multi-line mode (when there is no enough horizontal space) instead of scrolling? The issue - some users complain that scrolling doesn't work properly on some mobile devices.

Comment: Would be great to get a bug report about the non-working scrolling on some mobile devices, with more details about the actual devices, operating system, and browsers. And Vaadin version.

Comment: I may demo it on the real app, but the biggest issue with this - that thanks to your solution - I already fixed that ) And it was working on some screens and not working on another screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tabs part inside the `<vaadin-tabs>` component is flex container, and you can force that to wrap the contained tab elements.

```css
vaadin-tabs::part(tabs) {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Note, that this CSS should be in a global style sheet (e.g. `frontend/themes/mytheme/styles.css`), and not in a component-specific style sheet (e.g. `frontend/themes/mytheme/components/vaadin-tabs.css`) which is copied inside the component's shadow DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I added these styles. It works perfectly in FireFox but not in any of my other browsers .. not even Chrome. What might I have missed here?

Comment: @alexanoid How does it render? I had to add `vaadin-tabs { min-height: unset; }` (otherwise the wrapped tab overflowed vertically and wasn't visible)

Comment: Looks like I found the reason - the following notation works fine - `[part~='tabs'] {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}`

Comment: @Javier I just use the styles I posted in my previous comment. That's it. Now it is working in all browsers.

Comment: You should not need to unset the `min-height`. I updated the answer, to clarify where to put the CSS (I assume you placed it in a component-specific style sheet).